# keras LSTM feature dimension importance

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a LSTM model like below that takes sequence of 10 dimensions and predicts 2 dimensions.

```py
def CreateModel(X):
    #for number of hidden units
    outDim = 2
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=8, return_sequences= True, input_shape=(X.shape[1],X.shape[2])))
    model.add(LSTM(units=8, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(units=8))
    model.add(Dense(units=outDim))
    return (model)
```

My error function would calculate the `mean_square_error` based on `np.stack((y, y1))`. It would all be fine if they all had equal importance. But in this case, y has more importance and I would like my cost function to be weighed in favor of it. Is there any way of providing weights to feature dimensions?

I tried scaling y1 down ( `y1 /= 2`), keeping y unchanged but that has a weird impact on y and it no longer is neutral. (i am using min-max scaling and i suspect it shifts midpoint of y to some level other than 0.5).

I also tried writing custom error function as below; but there is no evidence that it improves things either

```
# y[:,0] provides value of prediction and y[:, 1] provides sign. 
# Idea is to penalize the samples more that go in opposite direction .
def keras_custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
        loss_val = K.mean(K.mean(K.square(y_true[:, 0] - y_pred[:, 0]) + (K.abs(y_true[:, 1] - y_pred[:, 1])/4)))
    return loss_val
```

Comment: Do you mean to take two means in your loss function? You're not passing an axis to either of them. You are also using both MSE (y0) and MAE (y1), which might affect your importance quantification.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Here y[:,0] provides value of prediction and y[:, 1] provides the sign. Idea is to penalize the samples more that go in opposite direction. Hence there is the element by element addition (not the addition of the MSE and MAE).

Comment: I mean in this code: `K.square(y_true[:, 0] - y_pred[:, 0]) + (K.abs(y_true[:, 1] - y_pred[:, 1])/4)`, you are using K.square and K.abs independently.

Comment: Also, if y1 is the sign, then this is a classification problem. Try passing MSE loss for y0 and a BCE loss for y1 since it can only be 0 or 1.